# Replace empty string for a item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am just trying to replace empty strings in a item that is part of ng-repeat so I can use this as an id for a div element. Works for the first empty space. I want a global replace and tried something like / /g, but the quotes in the code is messing it up or I am not doing it right.

I tried this

```
<div ng-repeat="list in list">
        <div id="{{list.name.replace(' ','_');}}" ></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to create a `function` and call it in your view.

Here's a *snippet* working:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
       {
          "name": "noempties"
       },
       {
          "name": "a empty string"
       },
       {
          "name": "more empties a a a a a"
       }
    ];
  
    $scope.replace_chars = function(obj) {
      return obj.name.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="lst in list track by $index">
        <!-- The ng-bind was used only to show how it was after replace -->
        <div id="{{replace_chars(lst)}}" ng-bind="'div id: ' + replace_chars(lst)"></div>
    </div>   
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked. Can you tell me why are you using the ng-bind. It works with out that as well.

Comment: Well, since you want only the div id replaced, the ng-bind doesn't matter. It was used only to display in the screen.

Comment: For a global replace function, this could be improved by making it more generic; passing in actual string value to operate on vs. an object graph (string vs. obj.name).

Comment: @TSmith, of course it can be. It was just an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bind

```
<div id="checkText(lst.name);" ng-bind="checkText(lst.name);"></div>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.checkText = function(text) {
    return text.replace(' ','_');
  };
```

Comment: How it differs from my answer?

Comment: Well, I answered 7 mins ago.

Comment: I don't think so my answer is exactly similar to yours